# How to create read-only memory buffer across multiple devices in OpenCL?

Tags: gpu, opencl, nvidia, amd-gpu

This is really an issue just for NVIDIA devices. For AMD cards, multiple command queues within a single context can be executed simultaneously, however, NVIDIA OpenCL [does not support this](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/415023/launch-kernels-in-parallel-/). One has to create multiple context objects in multiple threads in order to run the kernel on multiple devices simultaneously.

the downside of creating multiple context is that all `cl_mem` objects have to be created multiple times, one for each context. something like

```
     gmedia=(cl_mem *)malloc(workdevice*sizeof(cl_mem));
     for(i=0;i<workdevice;i++){
        OCL_ASSERT(((gmedia[i]=clCreateBuffer(mcxcontext[i],RO_MEM, sizeof(cl_uint)*(dimxyz),media,&status),status)));
        ...
     }
```

This becomes quite time and memory consuming if one has a large array to copy. In my case, the memory copying overhead became dominant and consumes many more GB memory before launching the kernel. When I am trying to launch this kernel over 8 GPUs (I have a total 11 GPUs), the code crashes due to memory limit.

I am wondering if there is a way to effectively share read-only buffers across multiple devices with OpenCL?

Alternatively, is there a way to launch simultaneous executions on multiple devices with NVIDIA OpenCL?

Comment: are you sure this is technically feasible at hardware level? not sure a card can access the memory of another one, thus this would not be such a surprise that you need to allocate memory on the very device you want to work with (even if you actually just finished with another one of the same kind just before)